# Clip Google Maps JS API ImageMapType to a polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I clip a MapType in Google Maps to an arbitrary polygon. For example, if I have a custom [ImageMapType](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#ImageMapTypes) that covers a large area (i.e. all the world), but I want to show it only inside a given polygon (i.e. one country).

Is there a way to clip the ImageMapType to a given polygon, or to implement a custom MapType to achieve this behaviour? It should allow for zooming and panning normally.

The rest of the map should stay the same, and there would be a MapType covering only a specific area. Therefore, it is not possible to simply overlay a polygon to cover the areas outside the polygon to display just what is needed.

Like so:

[image: Australia map with a clipped overlay on South Australia]

Server-side clipping is not an option.

Comment: One way could be to create a custom ImageMapType that covers the whole world, but is transparent everywhere except the area you want, and apply it as an [overlay map type](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes?hl=fr#OverlayMapTypes)

Comment: Like this? [maptype-image-overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image-overlay)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli, for that you would need access to modify the tiles, so it is not a client side solution.

Comment: @JonasHartmann that example looks like what I need, but, again, it considers server side clipping of the selected area

Comment: @Nicolas the only server side part of it that I see is where they store the image. But you cannot avoid storing an image in a server.

Comment: @Nikolas Is maybe [this](http://www.gewiss-saarland.de/) or [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18867/is-it-possible-to-gray-out-a-google-maps-map-except-for-some-area) what you're looking for? Furthermore, you can clip an image on client-side using something like [this](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/10/29/clipping-jpeg-images-into-non-rectangular-polygons-using-polyclip-js/) but I'm not sure if it is a solution or possible in this situation. Finally, maybe you could create a mask to polygon using [this](https://github.com/adammck/gmaps-v3-mask)

Comment: I just tried the last solution and I see that masking would't be a problem. Check [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/sacazibi/1/)

Comment: @JonasHartmann of course you cannot avoid storing the image on a server. The thing is that I don't have access to modifying the image on the server, so it has to be clipped on the client side...

Comment: @hex494D49 thank you for your solution. The problem is that I can't see how you could show a base map with that approach. What you seem to be doing is covering everything outside the polygon with a mask, and that necessarily will cover the base map...

Comment: I guess this question is old...but if @JonasHartmann solution is what you need/needed you could try converting the overlay image to a data URI and using that on the client side: - https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/

Comment: Hey Ben. I don't see how that would work; why would using a data URI instead of a normal <img> help with the clipping? BTW, the official answer from google is that this it no currently possible https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8162

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have written the code for an overlay map type that does what you want. Be sure to test in your target browsers. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sirkurt53/kstytcrc/)

```js
function ClipMapType(polygon, map) {
  this.tileSize = new google.maps.Size(256, 256);
  this.polygon = polygon;
  this.map = map;
}

ClipMapType.prototype.getTile = function(coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {
  var map = this.map;
  var scale = Math.pow(2, zoom);
  if (coord.y < 0 || coord.y >= scale) return ownerDocument.createElement('div');
  var tileX = ((coord.x % scale) + scale) % scale;
  var tileY = coord.y;
  // Your url pattern below
  var url = "https://khms0.google.com/kh/v=694&x=" + tileX + "&y=" + tileY + "&z=" + zoom;
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = url;

  var canvas = ownerDocument.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = this.tileSize.width;
  canvas.height = this.tileSize.height;
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var xdif = coord.x * this.tileSize.width;
  var ydif = coord.y * this.tileSize.height;

  var ring = this.polygon.getArray()[0];
  var points = ring.getArray().map(function(x) {
    var worldPoint = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(x);
    return new google.maps.Point((worldPoint.x) * scale - xdif, (worldPoint.y) * scale - ydif);
  });

  image.onload = function() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
    var count = points.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      context.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
    }
    context.lineTo(points[count - 1].x, points[count - 1].y);

    context.clip();
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    context.closePath();
  };

  return canvas;
};

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {
      lat: 15,
      lng: 15
    }
  });
  var polygon = new google.maps.Data.Polygon([
    [{
      lat: 0,
      lng: 0
    }, {
      lat: 30,
      lng: 30
    }, {
      lat: 0,
      lng: 30
    }]
  ]);
  var mapType = new ClipMapType(polygon, map);
  map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, mapType);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
</script>
```

**How it works**

Basically `ClipMapType` class is a MapType interface. `getTile` method of this interface is called with tile coordinates and zoom level to get tile for every tile. `ClipMapType` creates a canvas element to act as a tile and draws the tile image clipped to inside of the polygon. If performance is important, it can be optimized to work faster.

**Disclaimer**

Usage of Google tile servers by hacking the URL, probably violates Google Maps Terms of Service. I used it for demonstration and don't recommend using it in production. My answer is an attempt to give you an insight for you to create your own solution.

Comment: Are you able to update Fiddle to work again?
I need the same thing on my Angular Google Maps. User draw a polygon and I wont to inject tile image which I'm getting from weather API.

Answer (score 2):

Do you require Google Maps perse? I know Openlayers 3 provides better support for this kind of stuff. For example, take a look at [this](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/layer-clipping-webgl.html).

If you really must use Google Maps, I suggest implementing your own MapType and generate the tiles needed to cover your polygon area yourself using [MapTiler](http://www.maptiler.com/). (MapTiler also generates an example Google Maps implementation for you, so that shouldn't be too hard.)

Comment: Do you know of a way of doing it in OpenLayers that would not involve WebGL?

Comment: When you instantiate a new OpenLayers map you can set the preferred renderer in the options object you pass in ol.Map. Just set renderer: 'canvas'

Comment: Right, but the clipping method used in this example would break down (as it is relies heavily on WebGL), wouldn't it? That is my point.

Comment: Ah, yeah you're totally right. If you can't use WebGL I'd go for a custom tileset which covers just the area you need. MapTiler would be the way to go if you have a high-res version of your map.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you can't use normal masking strategies because you need to be able to see the lower layer. May I suggest SVG's more complete clipping suite? [See here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html).

The browser compatibility is good but not great, but you can absolutely accomplish what you're trying here (unless you need to pan/zoom the Map, then you're screwed until Maps implements such a thing).

Comment: I absolutely meant this with zooming and panning. I updated the question to reflect this!

Comment: Then I'm no help! Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`canvas.toDataURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) option in HTML5 to obtain the url that is required for `getTileUrl()` of `ImageMapType`.

```
getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
    var normalizedCoord = getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom);
    if (!normalizedCoord) {
      return null;
    }
    var bound = Math.pow(2, zoom);
    // reset and clip the preloaded image in a hidden canvas to your required height and width

    clippedImage = canvas.toDataURL();
    return clippedImage;
    }
```

- To set and resize the image to correct dimension, use [`canvas.drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)
- To clip the image from canvas to any non-rectangular dimension, use the [`canvas clip()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clip)
  [Sample code for canvas clipping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701798/a-reusable-function-to-clip-images-into-polygons-using-html5-canvas).

Answer (score 1):

You could use an svg clippath, together with the foreignobject svg tag to put a html document within the svg then clip it to the desired shape like this code taken from codepen.io/yoksel/pen/oggRwR:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo:700);

.svg {
  display: block;
  width: 853px;
  height: 480px;
  margin: 2em auto;
 }

text {
  font: bold 5.3em/1 Arvo, Arial sans-serif;
 }
```

```html
<svg class="svg">
    <clippath id="cp-circle">
      <circle r="180" cx="50%" cy="42%"></circle>
      <text
            text-anchor="middle"
            x="50%"
            y="98%"
            >Soldier Of Fortune</text>
    </clippath>
  
    <g clip-path="url(#cp-circle)">   
    <foreignObject width="853" x="0"
                y="0" height="480">
      <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <iframe width="853" height="480" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/RKrNdxiBW3Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </body>
    </foreignObject>
   </g> 
</svg>
```

http://codepen.io/yoksel/pen/oggRwR

Answer (score 0):

You could place a DIV above your map, with absolute positioning and high z-index. then, apply a polygon mask to that DIV like this:   `-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0);`

Comment: I need to apply the clipping to one one of the layers of the map, not the whole map.